# Make specified text in NSTextView Bold

Tags: objective-c, formatting, nstextview

I am using a little bit of code to change the text in an NSTextView

```
NSString *string = @"This is a title\n\nThis is some info";
[content setString:string];
```

I would like to make the text "This is a title" the only text that is bold when displaying in the NSTextView and the rest normal text. Is there any way to do this? Maybe like how the StackOverflow editor works? `__bold text here__`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to use an NSAttributedString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can just apply boldness as that's usually part of another set of glyphs. But how's this work...

```
NSString* textUnattributed = @"This is a title\n\nThis is some info";
NSMutableAttributedString* textAttributed = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textUnattributed];
[textAttributed addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
                       value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:16.0]
                       range:[textUnattributed rangeOfString:@"This is a title"]];
content.attributedText = textAttributed;
```

Comment: I get an error with prompt `Use of undeclared identifier 'prompt'`

Comment: @SteppingHat, whoops, I grabbed some code from one of my projects, let me fix.

Comment: all good. One other problem as well. `content.attributedText` isn't a thing I can apply to an NSTextView but instead I can use `content.attributedString` however I get an error `No setter method 'setAttributedString:' for assignment to property`

Comment: Also... for `range:[textUnattributed rangeOfString:...]` I get an error also saying `No visible @interface for 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'rangeOfString'`. In my case, I'm replacing `textUnattributed` with an array called `result`. Essentially taking the array, bit by bit and turning it into a massive string within a for loop. Its a multidimensional array and any part of the array where the second array is indexed 0 I want to bold. So in the for loop it would look like `result[i][0]`. Sorry for the complexity haha. But essentially how could I make this work with an array?

Comment: It might be time to fire up another SO question. I'll be happy to help you out over on that one too.

Comment: Done! You can find the new question at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840682/nstextview-making-bold-text-using-an-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23840682/nstextview-making-bold-text-using-an-array). Thanks for all your help! :)